# Angular GET http://localhost/ 401 (Unauthorized) error

Tags: angular, laravel, http, http-status-code-401

I have a problem loading the user data into the page. I get this Error: GET http://localhost/ 401 (Unauthorized).

In Laravel I've put this into my controller to get all user data:

```
public function index()
{
 $user = User::all(); return response()->json($user,201);
}
```

In Angular I've created a data.service file with this code:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DataService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  findAll(): Observable<User[]>{return this.http.get<User[]>('http://localhost');}
}
```

And In the app.component.ts file, I used this method to get the data:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  users$: User[];
  constructor(private dataService: DataService){}
  ngOnInit(){return this.dataService.findAll().subscribe(data => this.users$ = data);}
}
```

In the app.component.html file I've looped through the data:

```
<div *ngFor='let user of users$'>{{user.name}}</div>
```

Comment: nothing wrong with your Angular code. first try the GET request using postman.

Comment: what do you expect this url to even yield? `http://localhost` ??

Comment: I wonder, even if you correct your url or authorization headers, you might run into CORS issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this an error returned by angular or laravel? 
Also please note the following:

1. You're not specifying the port at localhost
2. You are defining user$ as an array not an observable, so the async pipe won't work, instead you can either declare user$ as an observable or remove the async pipe.

Here is the better solution:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  users$: Observable<User[]>;
  constructor(private dataService: DataService){}
  ngOnInit(){
    this.user$ = this.dataService.findAll()
  }
}
```

and in HTML keep your current code as it is:

```
<div *ngFor='let user of users$'>{{user.name}}</div>
```

Comment: I've found the solutuion. In Laravel first you have to login before you can get the Users when you call the api URL so I've removed the login mask so it show's you the Users in JSON format without a login. And I've added the observable Part and it worked! Thanks!